# HoloLens - Unity: How to change color of cursor?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, hololens, mrtk

I tried to change the color via script on runtime of the cursor and it worked to 75%:
[image]

`Mesh_top` is the only part that does not change the color and I dont know why.
All 4 parts use the same material, named "`cursormaterial`".
What I tried:

1. Changing the color by referencing to `cursormaterial`
2. Changing the color by getting the component `SkinnedMeshRenderer`
3. Trying to use `ProptertyBlock`

In all three cases I got the same result. The only thing that works is before hitting play I can change the color, this will change the color of the whole cursor. Changing it on runtime works only for 3 of 4 parts...´

--Edit--

```
    public SkinnedMeshRenderer cursorRendererOne, cursorRendererTwo, cursorRendererThree, cursorRendererFour;
private MaterialPropertyBlock _propBlock;
public Material material;

void Start()
{
    _propBlock = new MaterialPropertyBlock();
}

public void OnInputDown(InputEventData eventData)
{
    if (!isActivated)
    {
        //#1
        material.color = Color.blue;
        //#2
        cursorRendererOne.sharedMaterial.color = Color.blue;
        //#3
        cursorRendererOne.GetPropertyBlock(_propBlock);
        _propBlock.SetColor("_Color", Color.blue);
        cursorRendererOne.SetPropertyBlock(_propBlock);
        cursorRendererTwo.SetPropertyBlock(_propBlock);
        cursorRendererThree.SetPropertyBlock(_propBlock);
        cursorRendererFour.SetPropertyBlock(_propBlock);
        isActivated = true;
    }
```

Here u see the changed material, but the `mesh_top` looks but different:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a "Bug" (maybe an intended one?).

Open the `Animation` window (<kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>)

And in the hierachy select the `CursorVisual`

If you now go to the animation called `CursorWaitingAnim` you can see there is a keyframe for the top_mesh color.

[image]

This single keyframe causes that the color of that tile can not be changed on runtime. The reason is that the animator runs [after](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html) `OnInputDown` so it reverts the changes for any keyframed property.

So if you don't need the Waiting animation simply remove that keyframe.

[image]

=> you can manipulate the color at runtime again!

---

Alternatively you could replace it by a one that instead of fixing the color simply disables the `SkinnedMeshRenderer` instead which basically has more or less the same effect but doesn't screw the colors:

[image]